# como ignorar uma linha no dockerfile usando dockerignore?

Tags: docker

Eu preciso ignorar uma linha no dockerfile usando o dockerignore ou qualquer coisa que ajuda eu solucionar um problema. Estou enviando print dos erros que aconteceram.

Preciso ignorar a seguinte linha no dockerignore:
ADD . /home/hubot/node_modules/hubot-rocketchat
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O Arquivo [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) serve para excluir arquivos ou diretórios desnecessários do seu contexto de build, utilizado para agilizar o processo de build quando o diretório onde o build é realizado contém arquivos ou pastas pesadas.

Para ignorar uma linha no Dockerfile, basta comentar com # como informado na resposta anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode ignorar uma linha de um dockerfile a não ser que esta esteja comentada. Comentários são feitos com #.